# Lockup when unlocking screen saver

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, screensaver

I've had this happen a couple of times - screen saver kicks in, locks the screen, and when I put my password in to unlock it the system just seems to hang.

Cursor turns to the busy, HDD light flickers occasionally, but the only thing I can do at that point is power down.

This is on a desktop, not a laptop and according to the bios all the power saving is turned off.

Has anyone else seen this?  Is there a way to prevent it, or at least diagnose the cause?

Comment: What are your system specs, particularly graphics card?  

I used to have this problem fairly often. I think I narrowed it down to use of the closed source ATI drivers on a cheapo Radeon I was using. It had the symptoms of a memory leak in the driver or xserver. It didn't happen with the open source drivers and it went away completely with my new Nvidia card.

Comment: It's an N68 MB with an AMD chip, and an nVidia 9500 class card, using 180.x driver.  I was having random hangs, but they were complete lockups - the mouse wouldn't even work, whereas with this, I can move the mouse.

Comment: I faced the similar problem in the older versions of Ubuntu . Which version of Ubuntu you are currently using ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a manifestation of a long standing issue with the nvidia drivers. Have a look at this bug report discussing an almost identical issue:
[screensaver locks up X](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-180/+bug/338087).
If it helps, you might want to try the PPA mentioned in the comments to see if you can find a more bleeding-edge driver.

Look at your */var/log* files, specifically *Xorg.0.log*, *syslog* and *messages*, and see if you can spot any errors.

This has also been reported on the nvidia linux support forum [in this thread](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=123912&page=22) (starting with the post by darksorceror) with a follow-up poll [here](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=130669).

No real solutions in there I'm afraid. If this is bothering you enough, may I suggest you file a bug-report on [Ubuntu Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks Nagul! I had the exact same issue. It's comforting to know I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually fix your problem but instead of powering down you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

to end your X window session (you'll lose whatever you were working on, but hey at least you didn't have to reboot).

Comment: That needs the DontZap option disabled as by default in recent Ubuntu distros, Ctrl+Alt+Backspace is disabled.

Comment: or instead of the DontZap you could use the new shortcut: http://superuser.com/questions/15961/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-restart-x-window-manager-in-ubuntu-jaunty/15964#15964

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this, or a similar event. I get a screensaver that doesn't even give me the password box.

It seems to be a few screensaver modules with a subtle bug. Molecule is one that I recall doing this. I just disabled the apparantly faulty ones. However, I've switched to xscreensaver from gnome-screensaver so I have that flexibiltiy.