# What is the keyboard shortcut to restart x-window-manager in Ubuntu Jaunty?

Tags: ubuntu

I keep forgetting. The answer to this question never seems to be the first result in Google, it's always how to set it back.

So now it will be here for all to see.

Comment: it is a bit crazy to me too, but I seemed to always have to Google this answer, so I thought it should be here for reference, I guess I'm not the only person who can't seem to remember it. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shortcut you're looking for is: <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Sys Rq</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: awesome, I was wondering how to do those neat key styles. thanks, looks much better.

Comment: hehe, I just tried it! stupid me, I didn't expect it will shutdown all my applications/

Comment: this one has replaced the old `ctrl+alt+backspace`

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> might also be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I always use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Comment: as a default in 9.04 (Jaunty) that doesn't work. It's easy to set back I understand, but not the preference of the upstreamers I guess. ;)

Comment: I have to admit I really don't like the way Ubuntu is being put together. I noticed recently run levels also works differently which is highly frustrating when you use Fedora, RedHat and CentOS the whole day.